# ASP.NET MVC JQUERY Datepicker time problem

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I tryed some code examples from here&another forums but it still gets the date with time when I click the edit button. Here's my code

```
   <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2">License Date</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.L_Date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "date-picker" } })
        </div>
</div>

<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.js")"></script>
@section scripts{
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('.date-picker').datepicker({
                showOn:"both",
                buttonText: "...",
                dateFormat: 'dd.MM.yy',
                changeYear: true,
                changeMonth: true,
                firstDay: 1
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

It gives like " 2.07.2019 00:00:00 " format, I just want "2.07.2019 ".
Thank you.

Isn't there anyone have same problem.Any other help ?

Answer (score 1):

This is where and how you change the date format

```
$(function () {
        $('.date-picker').datepicker({
            showOn:"both",
            buttonText: "...",
            dateFormat: 'dd/MM/yy',//change format here
            changeYear: true,
            changeMonth: true,
            firstDay: 1
        });
    });
```

Check this for more formats. https://www.encodedna.com/jquery/ui-datepicker-widget-change-date-format.htm

Also you can change your textbox to

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.L_Date, "{0:d}", new { id = "your Id", @class="date-picker" })
```

**EDIT**

Another way to do this is to format the model before binding see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57223664/how-to-replace-the-line-break-tag-in-a-textarea/57224800#57224800)

```
@{ 
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
    Model.L_Date = Model.L_Date.ToString("d");//or any other formats
}
```

Comment: I tryed this format but its still same "2.07.2019 00:00:00"

Comment: Can you use TextBoxFor to try

Comment: Sorry , I need picker not a single box

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.Date format will be "dd/mm/yy"

```
 $('.date-picker').datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'});
```

Comment: link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
Try adding all scripts under @sectionScripts

Comment: Same ,nothing changed