# Replace the line break tag in a textarea?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In the field details the string can contain line break tags.
Example: "testing 
 more testing ".

How in the view can I replace the line break tag with a line break in the textarea?

error:

> Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.details.ToString().Replace("<br>", "\n"), new { @class = "form-control"})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest these three ways

**First**, use `@Html.TextArea`

```
 @Html.TextArea("details", Model.details.ToString().Replace("<br>", "\n"), new { @class = "form-control"})
```

**Second**, not part of your tag but very useful is using Javascript at page load, my example uses JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var re = "@Html.Raw(Model.details)";
    $("#details").val(re.replace("<br>", "\n"));
});
```

**Third**, To use using `@Html.TextAreaFor`, you need to replace the text before binding like:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
    Model.details = Model.details.Replace("<br>", "\n");
}

@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.details, new { @class = "form-control"})
```